# Cannot install Entity Framework Power Tools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I downloaded `EFPowerTools.vsix` from the official website. I made changes as shown in tutorial which shows how to install Power Tools in Visual Studio 2015. My Visual Studio version is 2015 Community.

[image]

This is my error:

[image]

Log:

[image]

Which step am I  making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have tutorial from Julie Lerman that worked for me, you can download updated VSIX right away, if you don't want to do the tasks.

http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/installing-ef-power-tools-into-vs2015/